# how to change filenames in folder cygwin?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, cygwin, sh

I have a folder contains meany files with the flowing convention:

```
#1_name.apk
#2_name2.apk
#3_name_name_name.apk
```

I want to change the names of all files and remove **only** the starting `#1_`
I tried to do this:

```
for file in *; do echo $file | mv ./$file $(awk -F '[/_]' '{print $2}'); done
```

The problem is when I have more than one `_` in the filename like `#3_name_name.apk`.

My question is, how do I split only the start tags?

Thanks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
for file in *; do echo $file; mv "$file" "${file:3}"; done
```

This assumes that 3 leading characters from the filename need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BASH's string manipulation:

```
s='#3_name_name_name.apk'
echo "${s#*_}"
name_name_name.apk
```